# Convert floating-point numbers with only zeros as decimal part to integers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, type-conversion, linear-algebra

I'm multiplying two matrices A and B. When I multiply A and B I should obtain the identity matrix, but sometimes instead of obtaining 0 and 1s, I obtain 1.0000 or -0.0000. Of course this is caused because of one the matrices has floating-point numbers.

Is it possible somehow to convert this entries automatically to integers (i.e. -0.0000 does not make any sense, and 1.0000 could simply be 1)?

Comment: Maybe `round`? Not sure what you want.

Comment: @Daniel Wow, incredible, `round` can be applied to a matrix directly?!! I didn't know...Do you think it's a good idea to apply `round` or I should stick to the original result? Of course you don't know exactly what I'm doing... In my case, I just want to show that the multiplication of `A` and `B` produces the identity matrix, but by rounding I could eventually hide some bugs that I might have...

Comment: It is MATLAB (MATrix LABoratory), you can apply most functions to matrices ;). Without knowing your context I don't know what's right in your case. If you know that your result is integer and **the precision error is <0.5,** use `round`. This is a case where I repeatedly use round. There might be other cases as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you just want to see, that the result of the multiplication does not differ by much from the identity matrix. This you could check with a code like:

```
Result= A*B
Id=eye(size(Result))
eps=.2 %tolerance
% bigError == 1, if there is a error bigger than eps for an entry in the matrix, 0 otherwise:
bigError=any(abs(Result(:)-Id(:))>eps)
```

Comment: I'd rely on the inbuilt [**`eps`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the syntax in the code below to achieve the rounding suggested above without unexpectedly hiding a bug from rounding values not close to 0 or 1.

```
% Values in matrix to be rounded if within tol.
RoundElim = [0 1];
tol = 1e-12; % ensure that tol is greater than eps 
             % (floating point relative accuracy).


n = 4;

In = eye(n);
A = rand(n,n);
B = In/A; % Inverse of A

C = A*B
Cprev = C;

% Eliminate rounding from 0 and 1 entries

for i = 1:size(RoundElim,2)
    C(abs(C-RoundElim(i)) < tol) = RoundElim(i);
end

C

ErrorInf = norm(C-Cprev,'inf')
```

If you just want to check that every entry in your matrix is close to that in the corresponding identity matrix, I would suggest using the 'inf' norm.